# How to remove Jquery event if another element has certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a simple dropdown plugin for small project of mine. I do not want to use ready plugins, I want to learn by making one on my own.

html:

```
<div>
  <span class="dropdown_triger">press</span>
  <div class="content dropdown-closed">
 </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
span{
  display:inline-block;
  background: green;
  padding: 5px;

}
.content{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.dropdown-closed { display: none; }
.dropdown-open { display: block; }
```

and JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').on('click', '.dropdown_triger', function(e){
     var $wrapper = $(this).parent();
     var $content = $(this).next();
     var $triger = $(this);
     if($triger.hasClass('selected')){
       $(document).off('mouseup.dropdownDocClick');
       console.log('hasClass');
     }
     $triger.toggleClass('selected');
     $content.toggleClass('dropdown-closed dropdown-open');
     $(document).on('mouseup.dropdownDocClick',function (e){
       console.log('fire');
       if (!$wrapper.is(e.target) && $wrapper.has(e.target).length === 0){
         if($content.hasClass('dropdown-open')){
           $content.toggleClass('dropdown-closed dropdown-open');
           $(document).off('mouseup.dropdownDocClick');
         }
       }
     });
   });
 });
```

Everything works except for this place:

```
if($triger.hasClass('selected')){
    $(document).off('mouseup.dropdownDocClick');
    console.log('hasClass');
}
```

I expect that mouseup event would not fire anymore but it does. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yr5uexc9/), just try it. If I open dropdown, mouseup event is attached to document and keeps firing until I have clicked outside container thus closed dropdown.

But if I close dropdown by clicking again on triger button(span in my example) event is not removed and I can not understand why?

Comment: according to the jQuery documentation the formatting of your 'off' should be something more like `$('body').off('click', '.dropdown_triger', actionfunction)` where `actionfunction` is the function you currently have assigned to your initial `on`. http://api.jquery.com/off/ currently don't quite understand your `'mouseup.dropdownDocClick'` method?

Comment: Well but I am using namespace. And it is working in callback.